# useContext returns undefined although it seems like everything is right

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I read the previous "useContext returns undefined" questions but none of them solved my problem. I'm building a weather app using nextJS, geolocation browser api and openweathermap api. I resolved all promises and stored its data into a state variable:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const GlobalContext = createContext({})

export default function GlobalContextProvider({children}){

    const [city, setCity] = useState("")
    const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState(0)
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState("")
    const [humidity, setHumidity] = useState(0)

    useEffect(()=>{
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async(position)=>{
    
          const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords
          
          try{
    
            const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}`)
            const data = await response.json(response)

            setCity(data.name)
            setTemperature(data.main.temp - 273)
            setWeather(data.weather[0].main)
            setHumidity(data.main.humidity)

          }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
          }    
          
        })
    
      }, [])
```

I even put all of that data into th value attribute in my context provider component:

```
return(
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={
            setCity,
            city,
            temperature,
            setTemperature,
            weather,
            setWeather,
            humidity,
            setHumidity
        }>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
```

And then I call the useContext hook to retrieve the "city" state variable value in another component:

```
import React,{ useContext } from 'react'
import { GlobalContext } from '../../context/globalContext'
import styles from './index.module.scss'

export default function Header() {
  const { city } = useContext(GlobalContext)
```

Every component is wrapped inside the  context provider component. I don't get whats going wrong. I know it isnt something when I set the state of this variable and the api calls return all the data it was suposed to return. I dont have a clue about whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever using multiple values in the context api you have to enclose it as an object, so just change to

```
value = {{
        setCity,
        city,
        temperature,
        setTemperature,
        weather,
        setWeather,
        humidity,
        setHumidity
    }} >
```

Comment: oh got it! thanks for  helping me bro!